# Force my AWS Lambda function to use X memory

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that i have given a memorySize of 7168 MB, and because i'm running a high computational task, it has to use most of this memory for it to be able to finish before the timeout i set (90 seconds), most of the time it uses the amount of memory i assigned, which is around 5500 MB to 4500 MB and works fine, but randomly, every several invokes, my lambda will only use 1000 or 500 MB, even though i set the memorySize of my lambda to 7168 MB. So i want to force my lambda to use at least 5000 MB of memory every time its invoked, so i don't keep running into this "error", i dont really know how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screeshot of error:

[image: error]

Comment: In case you are not aware of this: see [Lambda power tuning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/profile-functions.html). Using higher RAM configurations gives you correspondingly more CPU (and network) and does not necessarily increase the cost significantly (because the Lambda functions complete much quicker).

Comment: I think you'll need to describe more about the use case and the code. AWS Lambda will execute the code and data you provide and the environment will use the memory as required.

Comment: thank you for the response, i will read into this.

Comment: this is the example i am going off of: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/serverless-bert-with-huggingface-aws-lambda-and-docker-4a0214c77a6f)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of stuff going on with AWS Lambda behind the scenes. For example, if you have memory items in your code's global namespace, AWS Lambda will cache them. Also, you cannot enforce how AWS Lambda does its memory utilization.

You can set the AWS Lambda timeout to 15 mins or 900 seconds as a maximum and only pay for the duration and memory consumption. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: this wouldn't really solve my problem because i need the output to come out relatively fast.